# Stored procedure sqlserver 2008 only works with Visual Studio 2008 graphical user interface

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, user-interface, stored-procedures

I'm invoking a stored procedure on sql server r2 2008 through a java application. But I can't any result. Also, when executing the stored procedure from sql server (through a sql sheet or the graphical user interface) I can't get any results.

The stored procedure only works fine when executed from Visual Studio 2008, using the graphical user interface.

This is the main query of the stored procedure:

```
 SELECT TOP (1) 
    @IdLibroHistorico = SD.dbo.VM0001_CuadranteAgenteReal.Id
,@IdServicio = SD.dbo.TM0001_ServiciosMaestro.IdServicio
    ,@IdEntidad = SD.dbo.VM0001_CuadranteAgenteReal.IdAgenteReal
    ,@Negociado = SD.dbo.VM0001_CuadranteAgenteReal.TipoPersonal
    ,@Turno = SD.dbo.VM0001_CuadranteAgenteReal.IdTurno
    ,@UsuarioSysPol = SB.dbo.TSysUser.IdUsuario
FROM SB.dbo.TSysActivos
RIGHT JOIN SB.dbo.TSysUser ON SB.dbo.TSysActivos.Usuario = SB.dbo.TSysUser.IdUsuario
RIGHT JOIN SD.dbo.TM0001_ServiciosMaestro
INNER JOIN SD.dbo.VM0001_CuadranteAgenteReal ON SD.dbo.TM0001_ServiciosMaestro.IdServicio = SD.dbo.VM0001_CuadranteAgenteReal.IdServicio
    AND SD.dbo.TM0001_ServiciosMaestro.TipoPersonal = SD.dbo.VM0001_CuadranteAgenteReal.TipoPersonal ON SB.dbo.TSysUser.IdEntidad = SD.dbo.VM0001_CuadranteAgenteReal.IdAgenteReal WHERE (SD.dbo.TM0001_ServiciosMaestro.ServicioCorto = @Unidad)
    AND (
        @fechaDatetime >= SD.dbo.VM0001_CuadranteAgenteReal.HI
        AND @fechaDatetime <= SD.dbo.VM0001_CuadranteAgenteReal.HF
        )
ORDER BY ISNULL(SB.dbo.TSysActivos.Usuario, '') DESC
```

Anybody can tell me why?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You're assigning the results to vars so you won't see any until you select the vars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view VM0001_CuadranteAgenteReal was returning zero rows.